# Non-autonomous Dynamical system Sliding mode controller Error

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, evaluation

This code is a simulation of a sliding mode controller of a non-autonomous dynamic. When I use `ArcTan` in input, I receive an error. `ArcTan` is used instead of the `Sign` function that is usually used in SMC controller for smoothness of dynamics. If `Sign` is used instead of `Arctan` a different error is recieved.

```
ClearAll[x1, x2, x3];

c = 5;

k = 1;

r[t_] := Evaluate[2];
rdot[t_] := Evaluate[D[r[t], t]];
r2dot[t_] := Evaluate[D[r[t], {t, 2}]];

u[t_] := 1/
    b2[t]*(-(a21[t]*x1[t] + a22[t]*x2[t]) + 
     r2dot[t] -c (x3'[t] - rdot[t]) - 
     k*2/Pi*Arctan[((x3'[t] - rdot[t]) + c (x3[t] - r[t]))]);

a11[t_] := -0.4683*Exp[-0.03955*t] - 5.787*Exp[-2.308*t];
a12[t_] := (-1.248*10^(-8)*t^4 + 2.863*10^(-6)*t^3 - 0.0001976*t^2 + 
     1.004*t + 1.112)/(t + 1.115);
a13[t_] := -1.771*Exp[-3.312*t] - 0.3232*Exp[-0.2442*t]
a21[t_] := 
  8.044*Sin[0.176*t + 0.8637] + 8.672*Sin[0.06238*t - 2.693] + 
   3.578*Sin[0.3067*t - 2.259] + 1.41*Sin[0.4156*t - 4.424];
a22[t_] := 
  0.1411*Sin[0.04112*t - 2.51] + 0.03332*Sin[0.1928*t - 5.057] + 
   0.01927*Sin[0.329*t - 2.967] + 0.01594*Sin[0.4339*t - 4.503];
b1[t_] := -0.3851*Exp[-3.171*t] - 0.06556*Exp[-0.2131*t];
b2[t_] := 
  1.295*Exp[-((t - 48.88)/6.474)] + 1.826*Exp[-((t - 6.799)/27.72)] + 
   1.283*Exp[-((t - 37.72)/13.11)];
sol = First[
   NDSolve[{x1'[t] == 
      a11[t]*x1[t] + a12[t]*x2[t] + a13[t]*x3[t] + b1[t]*u[t], 
     x2'[t] == a21[t]*x1[t] + a22[t]*x2[t] + b2[t]*u[t], 
     x3'[t] == x2[t], x1[0] == -2, x2[0] == 2, x3[0] == -4}, {x1, x2, 
     x3}, {t, 0, 1000}]];
Show[Plot[r[t], {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-5, 5}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Brown}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 30}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Green, Dashed}, {Thick, Red, 
     Dotted}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-5, 5}}]]
```

Error is:

> NDSolve::ndsdtc: The time constraint of 1.` seconds was exceeded trying to solve for derivatives, so the system will be treated as a system of differential-algebraic equations. You can use Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Solve"} to have the system solved as ordinary differential equations. >>

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to your other question. Replace the following definitions in your code:

```
u[t_] := 1/ b2[t]*(-(a21[t]*x1[t] + a22[t]*x3'[t]) + r2dot[t] - 
         c (x3'[t] - rdot[t]) - k*2/Pi*ArcTan[((x3'[t] - rdot[t]) + c (x3[t] - r[t]))]);

sol = First[NDSolve[
   {x1'[t]  == a11[t]*x1[t] + a12[t]*x3'[t] + a13[t]*x3[t] + b1[t]*u[t], 
    x3''[t] == a21[t]*x1[t] + a22[t]*x3'[t] + b2[t]*u[t],
    x1[0]   == -2,
    x3'[0]  == 2,
    x3[0]   == -4},
   {x1, x3}, {t, 0, 1000}]]

Show[Plot[r[t], {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-5, 5}}, 
         PlotStyle -> {Thick, Brown}], 
    Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x3[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 30}, 
         PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Green, Dashed}}, 
         PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-5, 5}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but why with remove x2 is not any Error? Error of each code was different?! just with simplify equations errors become disappear!!!